# Unwanted little movement of element after transition/animation in css

Tags: html, css, sass

I have an absolute position element in CSS which contains tow absolute position as front-side of element and back-side of element that each one has back `backface-visibility: hidden;` when I hover the parent element then front-side disappears and back-side appears. In the back side I have button(notice : problem is here->) after 
rotating completely in Y axis the button moves a little to the bottom. How can I fix it ?
this is code : (notice above each persian text is a icon-font(linea-font) that i don't know how I should  add it here. and button is in the left one. ):

```css
@keyframes moveInLeft {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
        transform: translateX(-20rem);
    }
    90% {
        transform: translateX(2rem);
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 1;
        transform: translateX(0);
    }
}

*, *::after, *:before {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: inherit;
}

:root {
    font-size: 62.5%;
}

body {
    padding: 3rem;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    font-family: "Vazir", serif;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 1.6rem;
    line-height: 1.7;
    color: #777;
}

.paragraph {
    font-size: 1.6rem;
}

.paragraph:not(:last-child) {
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.u-center-text {
    text-align: center;
}

.u-mb-1 {
    margin-bottom: 1rem !important;
}

.u-mb-2 {
    margin-bottom: 2rem !important;
}

.u-mb-3 {
    margin-bottom: 3rem !important;
}

.u-mb-4 {
    margin-bottom: 4rem !important;
}

.u-mb-5 {
    margin-bottom: 5rem !important;
}

.u-mb-6 {
    margin-bottom: 6rem !important;
}

.u-mb-7 {
    margin-bottom: 7rem !important;
}

.u-mb-8 {
    margin-bottom: 8rem !important;
}

.u-mb-9 {
    margin-bottom: 9rem !important;
}

.u-mb-10 {
    margin-bottom: 10rem !important;
}

.u-mt-1 {
    margin-top: 1rem !important;
}

.u-mt-2 {
    margin-top: 2rem !important;
}

.u-mt-3 {
    margin-top: 3rem !important;
}

.u-mt-4 {
    margin-top: 4rem !important;
}

.u-mt-5 {
    margin-top: 5rem !important;
}

.u-mt-6 {
    margin-top: 6rem !important;
}

.u-mt-7 {
    margin-top: 7rem !important;
}

.u-mt-8 {
    margin-top: 8rem !important;
}

.u-mt-9 {
    margin-top: 9rem !important;
}

.u-mt-10 {
    margin-top: 10rem !important;
}

.power-circles {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
}

.power-circle {
    position: absolute;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    border-radius: 50%;
    perspective: 150rem;
    -moz-perspective: 150rem;
}

.power-circle__inside {
    box-shadow: 0 0 3rem 1rem rgba(61, 61, 61, 0.2);
    background: #fff;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border-radius: 50%;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    transition: all 1.5s;
}

.power-circle__inside--front {
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.power-circle__inside--back {
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotateY(-180deg);
}

.power-circle:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
}

.power-circle:hover .power-circle__inside--front {
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotateY(-180deg);
    transition: all 1.5s;
}

.power-circle:hover .power-circle__inside--back {
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotateY(0deg);
    transition: all 1.5s;
}

.power-circle--main {
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    width: 20rem;
    height: 20rem;
    background: #fff;
    box-shadow: 0 0 3rem 1rem rgba(61, 61, 61, 0.2);
}

.power-circle--small {
    width: 13rem;
    height: 13rem;
}

.power-circle--small-1 {
    top: 50%;
    left: 37%;
}

.power-circle--small-2 {
    top: 25%;
    left: 50%;
}

.power-circle--small-3 {
    top: 50%;
    left: 63%;
}

.power-circle--small-4 {
    top: 75%;
    left: 50%;
}

.power-circle__icon {
    margin-top: .7rem;
    font-weight: bold;
    background: linear-gradient(to right bottom, #12c2e9, #c471ed, #f64f59);
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    color: transparent;
}

.power-circle__icon--main {
    font-size: 6rem;
}

.power-circle__icon--small {
    font-size: 4rem;
}

.power-circle__fa-text--main {
    font-size: 1.6rem;
    margin-top: -3rem;
}

.power-circle__fa-text--small {
    font-size: 1rem;
    margin-top: -2.5rem;
}

.power-circle__en-text {
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.power-circle__en-text--main {
    font-size: 1.4rem;
    margin-top: 3rem;
}

.power-circle__en-text--small {
    font-size: 1.2rem;
    margin-top: 2rem;
}

.btn:link, .btn:visited {
    color: #3d3d3d;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 1.6rem;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
}

.btn--power-circle {
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: white;
    width: 50%;
    height: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    box-shadow: 0 0 3rem 0.2rem rgba(61, 61, 61, 0.5);
    line-height: 6.6rem;
    font-weight: 700;
}

.btn--power-circle:hover {
    box-shadow: 0 0 3rem 1rem rgba(61, 61, 61, 0.5);
}

.row {
    max-width: 114rem;
    margin: 0 auto 8rem auto;
}

.row::after {
    content: '';
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}

.row [class^="col-"] {
    float: left;
}

.row [class^="col-"]:not(:last-child) {
    margin-right: 6rem;
}

.row:last-child {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}

.row .col-1-of-2 {
    width: calc((100% - 6rem) / 2);
}

.row .col-1-of-3 {
    width: calc((100% - 2 * 6rem) / 3);
}

.row .col-2-of-3 {
    width: calc(((100% - 2 * 6rem) / 3) * 2 + 6rem);
}

.row .col-1-of-4 {
    width: calc((100% - 3 * 6rem) / 4);
}

.row .col-2-of-4 {
    width: calc(((100% - 3 * 6rem) / 4) * 2 + 6rem);
}

.row .col-3-of-4 {
    width: calc(((100% - 3 * 6rem) / 4) * 3 + 2 * 6rem);
}

body {
    padding: 0 !important;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    background: linear-gradient(to right bottom, #12c2e9, #c471ed, #f64f59);
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="fa">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/icon-font-arrow.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/icon-font.css">
    <title>خانواده وب | WEB-FAMILY.IR</title>
</head>
<body>
<header></header>
<main>
    <div class="power-circles u-center-text">
        <div class="power-circle power-circle--main">
            <div class="power-circle__icon power-circle__icon--main">
                <i class="icon-basic-world"></i>
            </div>
            <div class="power-circle__fa-text power-circle__fa-text--main">
                <h1>خانواده وب</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="power-circle__en-text power-circle__en-text--main">
                web-family.ir
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="power-circle power-circle--small power-circle--small-1">
            <div class="power-circle__inside power-circle__inside--front">
                <div class="power-circle__icon power-circle__icon--small">
                    <i class="icon-basic-video"></i>
                </div>
                <div class="power-circle__fa-text power-circle__fa-text--small">
                    <h1>دوره ها</h1>
                </div>
                <div class="power-circle__en-text power-circle__en-text--small">
                    Courses
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="power-circle__inside power-circle__inside--back">
                <a href="#" class="btn btn--power-circle"><span>ادامه</span></a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="power-circle power-circle--small power-circle--small-2">
            <div class="power-circle__inside power-circle__inside--front">
                <div class="power-circle__icon power-circle__icon--small">
                    <i class="icon-basic-video"></i>
                </div>
                <div class="power-circle__fa-text power-circle__fa-text--small">
                    <h1>دوره ها</h1>
                </div>
                <div class="power-circle__en-text power-circle__en-text--small">
                    Courses
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="power-circle__inside power-circle__inside--back"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="power-circle power-circle--small power-circle--small-3">
            <div class="power-circle__inside power-circle__inside--front">
                <div class="power-circle__icon power-circle__icon--small">
                    <i class="icon-basic-download"></i>
                </div>
                <div class="power-circle__fa-text power-circle__fa-text--small">
                    <h1>دانلود ها</h1>
                </div>
                <div class="power-circle__en-text power-circle__en-text--small">
                    Downloads
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="power-circle__inside power-circle__inside--back"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="power-circle power-circle--small power-circle--small-4">
            <div class="power-circle__inside power-circle__inside--front">
                <div class="power-circle__icon power-circle__icon--small">
                    <i class="icon-basic-message-multiple"></i>
                </div>
                <div class="power-circle__fa-text power-circle__fa-text--small">
                    <h1>پرسش و پاسخ</h1>
                </div>
                <div class="power-circle__en-text power-circle__en-text--small">
                    Q & A
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="power-circle__inside power-circle__inside--back"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</main>
<footer></footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please reproduce your issue with a minimal example https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. You can also [make runnable code snippets of html/css/javascript](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) by pressing Ctrl+M when you are editing.

Comment: I added it. is it ok?

Comment: I don't see the button moving to the bottom (firefox/windows here), do you experience it on a specific browser/environment?

Comment: Please check the links that I mentioned above. The goal is to remove the code that is not related to your issue.

Comment: @Kaddath Please pay more attention to the left circle on the back-side the circle of button changes a little . I use chrome

Comment: @jal_a all codes that are here are necessary here.

Comment: paid attention but still don't see the button moving, if something, the text inside moves some pixels to the left on Chrome, nothing really noticeable though, still nothing on Firefox, and looks like a text "repaint" on Opera. After further testings, there is an extra rotation on Edge, but it's buggy when you stop hovering in the middle of the transition..

Comment: @ThomasMakjon I also don't see the unexpected movement here in your example. Do you see the same behavior when you run the code snippet here?

Comment: @ThomasMakjon, the issue you face may be related to localization (you've mentioned Persian text) or browser specific. So, isolation of the issue will be very helpful.

Comment: I see the movement you're talking about. It's very minor, though annoying. Look into Firefox animation "jitter" or "smoothing". There are tricks to alleviate this, but I've never come up with 100% satisfaction. There is always going to be trouble when animating compound elements in a browser e.g. you make a fix to improve the div border, but now your font looks blurry, or vice versa.

Comment: @MarsAndBack thank you for your information. Do u know why the text looks blury?